# Delete friends requests?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to delete ALL friends request on Facebook at once using api or something..

There are over 1000 requests.

If API is not possible, then what the other solution?

Comment: Good question, but belongs on superuser.com - voting to migrate.

Comment: when someone is telling about something.com, the very first thing you should do it to type in your browser's address bar. :)

Comment: Having voted to migrate, i now see that http://superuser.com/faq specifically excludes questions about web apps like Facebook (which seems a bit odd - those SuperUser guys, eg?). This question probably actually belongs on http://webapps.stackexchange.com - but we don't have a migrate option for this. I would suggest the original poster ask it again there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook is already providing `Hide All Requests` Button.

And Still you can try below javascript code:

```
javascript:var inputs=document.getElementsByTagName('input');for(i in inputs){if(inputs[i].value == 'Not now' || inputs[i].value == 'Ignore')inputs[i].click();}
```

put this script on address bar and Hit Enter.

Comment: That java script working fine for fan pages requests but not friend request?

Comment: I tried this on friend requests... and its working... can you elaborate your question?

Comment: fixed the problem, 'Not Now' should be 'Not now'

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1 – Go to the Facebook Friends On Desktop version (Web) and Scroll Down to the Bottom** (Don’t forget to scroll down that list all the way to the bottom):

The link is : https://www.facebook.com/friends

**Step 2 – Go to the Chrome/Firefox CONSOLE :**

Use the keyboard shortcut ***Ctrl+Shift+I*** or select Inspect Element from the menu by right-clicking any element of the page.
Select **CONSOLE**

**Step 3 – Paste this script on the CONSOLE :**

***PS: FACEBOOK -French version***

```js
var list = document.querySelectorAll('[aria-label="Supprimer"]');
for(var i=0; i != list.length; i++) 
{   
list[i].click(); 
};
```

***PS: FACEBOOK -English version***

```js
var list = document.querySelectorAll('[aria-label="Delete"]');
for(var i=0; i != list.length; i++) 
{   
list[i].click(); 
};
```